# GROUPING_ID functionality

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't quite understand how this function works, I've been looking over the below documentation, and I have some issues.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510624.aspx

So, I understand how `GROUPING()` works perfectly, but the output for `GROUPING_ID` is quite impossible for me to comprehend how it's done because it's not the same with the explanation.

For example I have the following string of ones and zeroes: `010`. In the documentation it says it's equal to 2. Also I read in a SQL book that each byte (the rightmost) `is EQUAL` with 2 at the power of the byte position minus one.

So, (2^2 - 1) +  (2^1 - 1 ) + (2^0 - 1), but isn't that the same for each binary number? (100/101/110/etc), and the result isn't 2 either....

EDIT 1 : 
This is how the explanation from the book is:

> Another function that you can use to identify the grouping sets is GROUPING_ID. This
>   function accepts the list of grouped columns as inputs and returns an integer representing a
>   bitmap. The rightmost bit represents the rightmost input. The bit is 0 when the respective element
>   is part of the grouping set and 1 when it isn’t. Each bit represents 2 raised to the power
>   of the bit position minus 1; so the rightmost bit represents 1, the one to the left of it 2, then 4,
>   then 8, and so on. The result integer is the sum of the values representing elements that are
>   not part of the grouping set because their bits are turned on. Here’s a query demonstrating
>   the use of this function.

There has to be an error because there is no way a number is calculated by 2^(position) - 1, is it a mistake ? I've been calculating with 2^(bitposition) *1 and the outputs are correct.
For example the I've done this

```
GROUPING_ID(a,b,c),
GROUPING(a),
GROUPING(b),
GROUPING(c)
```

And let's say  we have the following output

```
3, 0, 1, 1
```

So our binary string is 011 and 3 is the output of the `GROUPING_ID` function, if we calculate the string

```
2^0 * 1 + 2^1 * 1 + 2^0 *2 = 1 + 2 + 0 = 3
```

There is no other logic that I see here, I cannot calculate with minus as the upper quote says, the thing is that on MSDN the weirder definition seems to be somewhat similar with this one:

> Each GROUPING_ID argument must be an element of the GROUP BY list. GROUPING_ID () returns an integer bitmap whose lowest N bits may be lit.
>
> A lit bit indicates the corresponding argument is not a grouping column for the given output row. The lowest-order bit corresponds to argument N, and the N-1th lowest-order bit corresponds to argument 1.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/06/sql-server-grouping-id-example.html

Comment: that example is guaranteed to return only 0 ( if it is a grouping element ) and 1 (if it's not a grouping element ), I saw for example outputs like 3,4,7 which I have no explanation ( look on the upper documentation ). the example that you gave me behaves exactly like GROUPING(name), since there's only one byte there can't be more than 1 or 0

Comment: does this explanation help you                                                  Lets say we have binary number 0101 we went from right to left 1->(2^0*1)=1 0->(2^1*0)=0 1->(2^2*1)=4 0->(2^3*0)=0 if we summerize all results we have 5 so 0101(binary)=5(decimal)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NIXZL-EROg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when they say

> Each bit represents 2 raised to the power of the bit position minus 1

they do not mean `2position - 1` but rather `2position - 1`. Apparently, for the purpose of their description they chose to count bits from 1 (for the rightmost bit) rather than from 0.

Secondly, each bit represents the said value *when it is set*, i.e. when it is 1. So, naturally, you do not do just

```
21 - 1 + 22 - 1 + ... + 2N - 1
```

but rather

```
bit1 × 21 - 1 + bit2 × 22 - 1 + ... + bitN × 2N - 1
```

which is the normal way of converting the binary representation to the decimal one and is also the method you have shown near the end of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have binary number 0101
we went from right to left

1->(2^0*1)=1

0->(2^1*0)=0

1->(2^2*1)=4

0->(2^3*0)=0

if we summerize all results we have 5

so 0101(binary)=5(decimal)

Comment: Please explain why this answer is not useful

Comment: Please add some commentary explaining what it is doing rather than just a chunk of opaque maths.

Comment: Lets say we have binary number 0101
we went from right to left
1->(2^0*1)=1
0->(2^1*0)=0
1->(2^2*1)=4
0->(2^3*0)=0
if we summerize all results we have 5
so 0101(binary)=5(decimal)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer people, can you please check the EDIT I've made minutes ago in the main post ? I am a bit confuse, the definition may have been bad from the start.